# Is there a way to make this query formula work? it was working before but I had to add more sheets and then it broke

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, array-formulas, google-query-language

Formula that combines all the sheets in my project and removes any empty cells

[image: Formula that combines all the sheets in my project and removes any empty cells]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, change this:

```
;},
```

to this:

```
},
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped. It's always the smallest details